# $http not recognized in Link Function in Angular JS Custom Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I want to use HighCharts for rendering Stacked Bar Charts.

```
app.directive('testDirective', function() {
  var directive = {};

  directive.restrict = 'EA',
  directive.controller = function($scope, $element, $attrs, $http) {
    populateData($scope, $element, $attrs, $http);
  },
  directive.template = '<div id="container" style="margin: 0 auto ;min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; height: 400px;">working</div>',
  directive.link = function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
  };

  return directive;
});


function populateData(scope, element, attrs, http) {
  var request = http.get("json/HighCharts.json");
  scope.seriesData = {};
  request.success(function(data, status) {
    scope.seriesData = data;
    plotChart(scope, element, attrs);
  });
}

function plotChart(scope, element, attrs) {
  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart : {
      renderTo : scope.seriesData.id,
      type : scope.seriesData.chart.type,
      events : {
        click : function(e) {
          console.log('Chart clicked');
        }
      }
    },
    title : {
      text : scope.seriesData.title.text
    },
    xAxis : {
      categories : scope.seriesData.xAxis.categories
    },
    yAxis : {
      min : 0,
      title : {
        text : scope.seriesData.yAxis.title.text
      }
    },
    legend : {
      reversed : true
    },
    plotOptions : {
      series : {
        stacking : scope.seriesData.plotOptions.series,
        point : {
          events : {
            click : function() {
              alert('Category: ' + this.category + ' ' + this.x + ' ' + this.y);
            }
          }
        }
      },
    },
    series : scope.seriesData.series
  });
}
```

The problem above I am facing is I am manipulating DOM in the **Controller** function which should be done in the **link** function.

Can somebody explain how to call A REST service in link function and then plot the chart on SUCCESS of Service.

Also, if someone can please explain on what benefits can angular provide here (2 way data binding).

Comment: But this is not a _problem_, it's something you learn by reading the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http - also this has nothing to do with two way data binding but with nice readable and maintainable MVVM code.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv I got an example in git hub which is serving the purpose...https://github.com/rootux/angular-highcharts-directive

Comment: That code does not use services in any way. Is the question "How do I write an AngularJS service that uses `$http` to query a web service"? And then "How do I use said service in my controller?" And then "How do I bind the result of that service call to a directive?". If those are the questions then you should read the documentation and try the examples it includes.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv yeah i am reading the documentation and trying to understand it. However the custom directive Scope is little confusing.

Comment: There are hundreds of questions  on SO about scopes. There are hundreds of articles on the internet about them. And there's the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope